# How can I prevent a custom key bind from making a noise?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, userscripts

Rather vague title, I know, but I'm binding a custom key event to the `document` object to catch <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> combination keypresses, like this:

```
document.body.onkeydown = function(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    var keycode = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
    if (keycode === 82) {
        if (event.altKey) {
            if (!canReload) {
                canReload = true;
                window.location.href += "#doGreaseRefresh";
            } else {
                canReload = false;
                window.location.href = window.location.href.replace("#doGreaseRefresh", "");
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The code runs as expected but also produces a rather annoying "beep" sound as well. How can I prevent this? `return false` didn't prove to be the answer, so I'm wondering if it's even possible.

Oh, and if you're wondering, this is in a Chrome userscript (Content script) to refresh Stack Overflow's home page every 10 seconds if I've pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, and to stop refreshing once I've pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> again. :)

Comment: FYI: Your script may become irrelevant in the future when/if [real-time updating](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125677) is deployed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the heads up. This is a decent fix for me for now, though, if I can get that silly sound fixed.

Comment: Untested, but does `preventDefault()` get you anywhere? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault (I can't even get my browser to beep with your code... what browser are you using?)

Comment: @ZachB: I'm using Chrome on a Windows 7. Thanks, I'll check out `preventDefault()`, although `return false` technically does that already.

Comment: Not being able to stop the beep is apparently a bug in Chrome:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=105500. `return false` works in Firefox without a beep.

Comment: @ZachB: That sucks. Oh well. I'm just going to have to live with it. Thanks for looking into this! Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not being able to stop the beep is apparently a bug in Chrome: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=105500. `return false` works in Firefox without a beep.

Cheers-

Answer (score 1):

[As ZachB points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10566301/331508), this appears to be a bug with Chrome.

To work around this annoyance:

1. Go into the Windows control panel.
2. Select *Sounds* or *System Sounds*
3. Assign `(None)` for the sound of the `Default Beep`.
   (I like to do this anyway, since it's 50 times more annoying than it is useful).

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks for the tip. I was specifically looking for Chrome but this is a good solution. +1